# ¿Cómo mostrar un formulario desde el con C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, scroll

Buen día, tengo un mini proyecto didáctico compuesto por varios formularios. La cosa es que, cuando se abre uno de estos formularios, nunca comienzan por el principio, se abren con el scroll en una posición diferente a la inicial.
Adjunto foto para que se entienda mejor[image: A la derecha se puede ver como el scoll está casi a la mitad]

Quisiera saber cómo solucionarlo, por favor. Está hecho en C#, es una aplicación de windows form hecha en SharpDevelop 5.1.
Gracias.

Comment: Pon el código que has intentado, y explica que significa "nunca comienzan por el principio"

Comment: En sí el código de ese formulario es más que nada para el contenido del formulario, para intentar solucionar el problema traté con un focus en el label que contenía el título (eso fue hace tiempo) y no me ayudó. Con "nunca comienzan por el principio" me refiero a que ejecuto el código, hay un formulario con un menú que contiene 13 opciones para llevar a distintos formularios cada uno, al dar click en cualquiera abre un nuevo formulario con su respectivo contenido (texto, imágenes, botones, radiobutton etc), al abrir dicho formulario el scroll ya está deslizado hacia abajo, es decir, en lugar +

Comment: en lugar de mostrar el título, la introducción al tema, ya muestra información adelantada, como si el scroll hubiese sido deslizado antes de abrir el formulario

Comment: Cuando guardaste el form, lo guardaste en ese lugar o en el principio???

Comment: Sharpdevelop no lo conozco. Pero no hay magia en el asunto, en algun lado debe estar el codigo que produce ese comportamiento. Debes buscar el codigo que configura la ui y mostrarlo para poder ayudarte